# How to close a ticket I opened myself in sourceforge.net projects?

Tags: sourceforge

I want to close https://sourceforge.net/p/yagf-ocr/tickets/58/ because I found out that my request was invalid after opening the ticket. The question seems to be valid for all of sourceforge.net's tickets.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest contacting the project administrator:
https://sourceforge.net/u/yagf-lw/profile/

Looking at how the permissions are set for the tickets tool for this this project, it looks like he/she is the only one that can close tickets.

Comment: Well, the ticket is still open :-(